# How to resize Mobile logo

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, header, wordpress-theming

I am trying to resize the logo on [my site](https://9xz.a2f.myftpupload.com/) when viewed on a **mobile phone** but no code seems to work. I have asked the theme developer and he is no help. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: logo image or the div containing the logo ?

Comment: maybe both? I have been trying to resize the logo but maybe the div is the problem...

Comment: reduce the width for the div then